# Collectibles, Medals and Ribbons in Sniper Elite 4

Tags: sniper-elite-4

I've been perusing google for a while to answer my question(s) but all that seems to come up are [guides](http://www.ign.com/wikis/sniper-elite-4/Collectibles) on how to get Collectibles, Ribbons or Achievements.

I've gotten quite a few of the collectibles in each of the missions as I've played them, and I've already earned a lot of ribbons and medals for various accomplishments or (killing) tasks.

**My question is, what do these actually get you, if anything?**

**Is there some sort of money (in-game credits for guns etc) that you get? EXP towards leveling up? Skins for guns? Or is it for show?**

I think some of them warrant Achievements/PSN Trophies, but I'm not sure if that's all they are for.

Comment: I've found that medals earn XP but still unsure on the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of my own testing and some other research it appears to go as follows:

Collectibles are for achievements/trophies and those that desire 100% completions of games.

Medals and Ribbons each earn you XP towards leveling up, but otherwise don't mean much or grant you anything. They are a way to track how much you've done X or Y activity/action but that's about it.